# Firebase Backend custom domain for NextJS App Hosted on Vercel

Tags: firebase, next.js, vercel, godaddy-api

So I've made a NextJS App and am using firebase for authentication and firestore.
I've bought a domain from GoDaddy and am currently hosting it on Vercel.

Everything is working as intended except that I cannot add a custom domain for firebase (when users click the login button). It still shows project-uid.firebaseapp.com

Is there any way to change that?

I cannot host my app on firebase hosting (since I lose SSR & ISR and I've some APIs too, also NextJS + Cloud Functions/ Cloud Run setup is unnecessarily complicated).

I tried adding a custom domain but it never gets verified ( been at it for 3 weeks now).

Comment: "Is there any way to change the project-id without creating a new firebase project?" No there isn't. I recommend removing this part of your question to prevent somebody from answering only that (or marking it as a duplicate, as this has been asked before) and ignoring your earlier question.

Comment: Ok yeah, my bad!

Comment: Your site can't be verified unless you update the DNS to point at Firebase Hosting (which you cannot if it's currently pointing at Vercel).

Answer (score 6):

By default, Firebase Auth uses the default subdomain for your project, which is `<project-id>.firebaseapp.com`.  You can customize that to any Firebase Hosting-hosted domain using the steps [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#expandable-4). (You'll need to update the authDomain in your Firebase config, and add the domain as authorized in Firebase Auth and Google OAuth).

While it cannot use a domain hosted on Vercel for this (since the redirect handler won't exist), you still have a couple options:

1. Use a subdomain (like `auth.mydomain.com`), and set that up with Firebase Hosting and Auth. You'll need to update your DNS to point all request to that subdomain to Firebase.
2. Add a new non-custom domain site to Firebase Hosting (`<custom-name>.web.app`) and configure that with Firebase Auth.